# Nuxt | Как сохранить токен и получить его в хранилище

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

Делаю магазин на наксте, нужно сохранить токен пользователя в куки или localStorage, чтоб токен сохранился.
При загрузке страницы хочу в store получить токен через localStorage - пишет что localStorage in undefined, пытаюсь сохранить куками - document in undefined.

Я понимаю, что это связано с тем, что проект загружается на сервере, следовательно и storage, и там не ни куков, ни локала.

Прошу объяснить и помочь мне как это все работает и что мне делать, чтобы решить проблему.

Нет ли никакого хука в наксте, который вызывается при работе с клиентской частью.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/ не пробовал?

Comment: Пробовал, но пишет

Comment: Cannot read property '$auth' of undefined - когда пишу token: this.$auth.$storage.getUniversal("token")||""

Comment: либо же
$auth is not defined - когда пишу token: $auth.$storage.getUniversal("token")||""

Comment: а плагин настроил?

Comment: Да, в принципе, я уже разобрался с бедой. Сделал костыль, но рабочий.

Comment: Просто считывал не в сторе, а nuxtServerInit